# Beamer Metropolis \patchcmd error after texlive 2016 update

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I did a routine update of my TeX Live 2016 installation on Linux yesterday (Jan 6, 2017), and now when I try to LuaLaTeX a source that used to compile fine, I get

```
! Package beamerfontthememetropolis Error: Patching section title failed.
...
l.263 \patchcmd
             {\beamer@@frametitle}
```

The same thing happens when I LuaLaTeX the file `demo.tex` that is part of the `beamer-metropolis` distribution.

Answer (score 6):

The latest `beamer` release fixes an issue with hyperlinks and subsections  (see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/ef419391cbe5245cabf3b77c89b58023fb253c95 and https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/350). This means that the line that the theme is trying to patch has changed. The theme code will need to be updated to allow for this: I have [logged a pull request](https://github.com/matze/mtheme/pull/250). (There is also a fix in the pull request to another issue which makes it impossible to simply ignore the patch problem!)